# Why in shouldReceiveTouch does my gesture recognizer always report being tapped in the same location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([recognizer locationInView:self.view]));
    ...
```

Every time I tap, however, I get `{0, -64}`. No matter where I tap. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe the view you passed as argument is not the good one. Try to put as argument nil, it will give you the coordonates of your touch in the entire window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the expected behavior because, "This method is called before touchesBegan:withEvent: is called on the gesture recognizer for a new touch". So, I think this means the recognizer won't know about its location yet. To get the location, use the touch argument provided instead:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint([touch locationInView:self.view]));
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that. Cheers.

Comment: I need to keep my eyes open. Perfect answer, thanks!